# Java servlet form action issue

Tags: java, servlets

I've attached my java project to the source packages of a java web application. I made a single servlet called "System" and what I'm trying to do is create a front end for my backend application.

But the issue I have is that in my "processregister" form, I can't get it to re-direct to my second action of "processreadregister" on the submit action. So when a user fills in the form it I can get the info and then call my set's for my back-end to do my registering, and obviously I can see whether it was succesfull or not.

Not used to servlets so I'm probably going completely wrong and calling the wrong action.

Code sample:

```
package HPC;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
import hpcproject.HPCSystem;
import hpcproject.JobRequest;
import hpcproject.User;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 *
 * @author Kieran
 */
@WebServlet(name = "System", urlPatterns = {"/System"})
public class System extends HttpServlet {

    HPCSystem System = new HPCSystem();

    public enum OPCode {
// specify enums to methods

        BOOKING, READBOOKING, NOTHING;

        public static System.OPCode resolve(String str) {
            try {
                return valueOf(str.toUpperCase());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return NOTHING;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        switch (System.OPCode.resolve(request.getParameter("action"))) {
            case REGISTER:
                processRegister(request, response);
                break;
            case READREGISTER:
                processReadRegister(request, response);
                break;

        }
    }


    protected void processRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        User testUser = new User();
        System.RegisterUserWithSystem(testUser);
        // point where it goes

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Register Process</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<FORM NAME ='register' ACTION ='readregister' METHOD='POST>'");
        // SORT OUT ISSUE HERE!!!
        out.println("<input type='hidden' name='action' value='readregister'>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Login ID:");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' name='user'>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Password:");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE='PASSWORD' name='password'>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Department:");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' name='department'>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Email:");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' name='email'>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("First name:");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' name='fname'>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("Last name:");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE='TEXT' name='lname'>");
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("<INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' VALUE='Submit' onclick=setType('readregister') >");
        out.println("</FORM>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    protected void processReadRegister(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        User testUser = new User();


            String id = request.getParameter("user");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String department = request.getParameter("department");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String myfirstname = request.getParameter("fname");
            String mylastname = request.getParameter("lname");

            testUser.setUserID(id);
            testUser.setUserPassword(password);
            testUser.setUseDepartment(department);
            testUser.setUserEmail(email);
            testUser.setUserFname(myfirstname);
            testUser.setUserLname(mylastname);

            if (System.RegisterUserWithSystem(testUser)) {
                out.println("User added successfully");
            } else {
                out.println("Failed to add user");
            }
             out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Charts</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>View Charts</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");


    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't closed any of your inputs `<input ... />` by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` attribute in a `<form>` tag "[specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)". You are using `ACTION ='readregister'` and trying to do a `POST` to the `readregister` which makes no sense since you don't have a mapping for that. Try to change the `action` attribute to `/System` which is the mapping of your servlet.

You have other small mistakes:

```
    out.println("<FORM NAME ='register' ACTION ='readregister' METHOD='POST>'");
```

should be

```
    out.println("<FORM NAME ='register' ACTION ='readregister' METHOD='POST'>");
```

notice the end single quote `'` before the `>`.

You should really look into JSPs and different html rendering technologies for Java servlets. Writing html directly into java is really bad practice.

Comment: thanks very much, going through nicely now, like you say those small mistakes are often hard to spot